# How do I get Hexchat to accept python 3.7+

Tags: python, hexchat

When I install Hexchat and say I want the python plugin, it insists that I use python 3.6   I already have python 3.7.  Is there a way to get hexchat to accept this later version?

Comment: What do you mean "it insists"?

Comment: It offers python 3.6 to install (as well at a python 2.x ).

Answer (score 2):

Python versions are not inter-compatible on Windows, so you have to build HexChat from source against the different version:

Build instructions: https://hexchat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/building.html
Example of updating Python: https://github.com/hexchat/hexchat/commit/63e9c721148f8a91bc68484c3f9ee42cfbc4316f

(If you test this and submit this change upstream I will accept it, just haven't gotten around to it)